# How Can i make (my token / eth ) paring as / usdt

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, usdt

I launch new token /eth  how can i make it /usdt

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a new liquidity pair on the exchange you are using. You will send your token and usdt to provide liquidity to the new pair. This  is also how you will set the initial price.

here is an article on how to do this with uniswap:
https://medium.com/singularitydao/how-to-add-liquidity-on-uniswap-d658ca935d6d